# Using schema.org microdata for Database Content

Tags: microdata, schema.org

I was wondering if one can mark text fields with schema.org microdata for fields which will contain values retrieved from a database, but which are initially empty upon loading the web page. Basically, I have some fields that I would like to mark using microdata, which will not contain any data until the values are retrieved from a database, the population of which would be initiated by users.

Answer (score 0):

The microdata format is about making data machine-readable.

You 'could' mark up the text fields but I'm not sure why you'd want to.

A search engine will only see the empty field which it won't be filling it in, so no help there.

It's possible that a browser could do something with that data after the user has filled it in, but I can't imagine what.

If your form is saved and presented on another page, then that page is a perfect candidate for microdata markup.